# How did Maeve get there?

Tags: the-boys-2019

In *The Boys*' finale,

> Maeve joins the fight against Stormfront and saves everyone.

There are two issues with that.

1. How did she know where to go? Nobody told her where they were going to be.
2. How did she get there? She doesn’t have flight or super speed, and there were no vehicles visible in the scene that could have been hers.

Comment: She appeared from nowhere in the episode before that too.

Comment: The magic of a deus ex machina.

Comment: She does have super speed.

Comment: @Paulie_D maybe captain America level speed but definitely not a-train level